# HLSL blur glitch with channel selection

Tags: graphics, shader, hlsl, artifacts, visual-artifacts

After playing around with blur i copied from visual studio shader graph, i put one filter condition (by any channel, doesn't matter), then it resulted into 
[this](https://vk.com/doc222878569_495384059?hash=141fc8e59e9ea323f2&dl=cfe35298ee711600a6). How is that can be explained?

Comment: tex is not initialized, do float4 tex = 0 it or use an else/ternary op with your condition

Comment: Yeah, but i rather wonder why compiler has missed it. Seems, it has a bit poor case tracing or something?